# D3.js text enter (within svg) transition opacity 0 to 1 won't end at 1

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, opacity

I am trying to have my text enter selection transition opacity from 0 to 1 with the following code. Without the transition and opacity setting, text appears as expected.

*But with this code, opacity starts at 0 but never becomes 1; and text value does not get added?*  [All other transitions in my code work as expected].

```
/**
   * @param text
   *           selection with data to add text from & truncate by, with a
   *           delay.
   */
  function addBubbleTextByData ( text ) {
     text.style( "opacity", 0 ).transition().delay( 1.1 * transitionDelay )
           .style( "opacity", 1 ).text(
                 function ( bubbleDatum ) {
                    var bubbleDatumText = ""; // for bubbles too small for any text
                    if ( bubbleDatum.r > 15 ) {
                       // Bubble is large enough to fit text
                       bubbleDatumText = bubbleDatum[JSON_NAME_KEY].toString().substring( 0,
                             bubbleDatum.r / 4 );
                    }

                    return bubbleDatumText;
                 } );
  }
```

Comment: @Incodeveritas "fill-opacity" instead of "opacity" worked, thanks!  Yes, svg was the parent.  If you want to make an answer instead of a comment, I will accept it if you want the rep.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's an SVG, you will need to mod `fill-opacity`.

```
text.attr( "fill-opacity", 0 ).transition().delay( 1.1 * transitionDelay )
           .attr( "fill-opacity", 1 ).text(
                 function ( bubbleDatum ) {
                    var bubbleDatumText = ""; // for bubbles too small for any text
                    if ( bubbleDatum.r > 15 ) {
                       // Bubble is large enough to fit text
                       bubbleDatumText = bubbleDatum[JSON_NAME_KEY].toString().substring( 0,
                             bubbleDatum.r / 4 );
                    }

                    return bubbleDatumText;
                 } );
```

Comment: Thanks!
I think adding a .duration also ultimately was necessary; but your answer was at the heart of what I needed!

Comment: Duration shouldn't have been necessary but I'm sure made it look better.

Comment: Without duration, the opacity doesn't have any time to visibly transition (fade in) from 0 to 1.  It just "blinks" from "invisible" to "visible", and is therefor a trivial transition as such.